# How do we want to handle tagging for questions related to WoW Classic?

Tags: discussion, tags

WoW Classic released legally on August 26, 2019. For the most part, it is the game as it was in version 1.12.1 (September 2006). At this point in time, it is unclear if it will remain that way, effectively acting like the version selector in [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft), or if future content will be developed, more akin to [oldschool-runescape](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oldschool-runescape).

How do we want to approach tagging these questions? We could create a new tag for it, or we can use the existing [world-of-warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft) tag. I created [world-of-warcraft-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft-classic) before realizing that it didn't exist yet, and want to make sure that we don't create a large cleanup effort for ourselves down the line anyway.

Comment: I think it's deserving of its own tag, considering how much the game has changed in the past 13 years.  Problems faced in the current game are not necessarily representative of problems in classic, and vice-versa.

Comment: @MBraedley I tend to agree, plus given that the site did not exist in 2006, I'd be surprised if there were any relevant answers On Here (excepting maybe some related more to the blizzard client)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[world-of-warcraft-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft-classic) would be the appropriate tag,  given the circumstances.

The base game has diverged significantly since the September 2006 version, and it will be easier to treat it as completely separate version. There might be some overlap, but it's not worth muddying the main game tag with questions that don't apply to it.

Comment: If it turns out an answer also applies to the non-classic version, questions can be tagged [wow] as well as [wow-classic].  (That's possibly prone to becoming outdated for [wow] but not [wow-classic], at which point it could in theory be untagged again to be just [wow-classic].)  Anyway, on Stack Overflow it's not rare to tag a question C++ and also C++11 (but not C++17) for example.  [wow] and [wow-classic] questions don't have to be disjoint sets.

Comment: @PeterCordes that makes sense if the question covers both games. Retagging a question based on its answer will probably result in a bunch of badly tagged questions after a few patches when the answer no longer applies to one of the games (and most people won't notice). Anyway, right now I don't see much of that happening. The only thing classic and retail have in common is the bnet client, which has its own tag, ...or a few basics, such as some races and classes.